autoload Does not work on hosting but Work properly on local server
After uploading the website files to the hosting, it does not work autoload .  It works properly on the local server.
this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\Models\User" not found in    /home1/ppamfste/public_html/index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 

/home1/ppamfste/public_html/index.php on line 5
I use composer dump-autoload
This image shows the file paths.
Works properly on local server



How does your autoloader configuration look like? As far as I see, you use a lower cased m for models in the directory name, but an upper cased M for Models in the namespace. This might work on some systems and not on others, so try to be concise

Tried this one and nothing changed.

Show contents of composer.json - it's there, where the path for the namespace is registered!

"Tried this one" - what does that mean?

The problem was in the classes names .. the files names are in the lowercase letter and the class names are in the uppercase letter  ,
example: File name > user.php , Class Name > User ......
If you want to complete your answer and publish the answer, I will choose it as the correct answer.

Change the file names to be the same as the class names. If the first letter is capital, the file name will be the same letters.
